# Why will SQL query work with one value and not another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column for `usernames`. There are two rows in my table. One has a value of

```
Example@Example.com
```

and the other has a value of

```
AllenPHundleyo5Y3SDKs8bGmailmFaGC4r2xvcom
```

The second email is so different because this is an email that has been passed through a function on my site which makes it safe to display whatever a user has input into the database. (Protects against the user writing code.)

However if I use the `EXACT SAME QUERY` to get each of the rows,

```
Example@Example.com
```

works, but the other doesn't. I.E.:

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='AllenPHundleyo5Y3SDKs8bGmailmFaGC4r2xvcom'
```

Pulls up nothing where,

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='Example@Example.com'
```

does. It is not a matter of the query being inaccurate in the value. I used page find to find exactly `AllenPHundleyo5Y3SDKs8bGmailmFaGC4r2xvcom` in my table. Why is this happening?

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? doesn't return anything? throws off an sql error?

Comment: "page find"? ...and are you sure there are not leading or trailing whitespace in the first string you could have missed?

Comment: @MarcB, the query goes through, however nothing is displayed.

Comment: Since we can't see the algorithm that creates the "escaped" value, it's hard to know what it contains. Inspect it with a hex editor, and check its `strlen()`  to verify that it contains _only_ the printable characters you are seeing and querying. There could be more in there than is visible.

Comment: A recommendation - it is generally not advisable to _store_ an escaped string (for exactly the reasons you're encountering) but instead to always store the original string and handle output escaping only at the time you actually write output.

Comment: @Allenph: then probably no records were matched and you're getting an empty result set. you need to check `numrows()` or whatever your db library provides. a `select` which returns no rows is NOT an error/failure - it's a perfectly valid result that just happens to be empty.

Comment: @Uueerdo This was it. Simple matter. I left spaces in it. Stupid mistake, but leaving the question in case others make the same mistake.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You're right, however the client would like the string encrypted, so it's going to be a mess anyway, might as well apply it before the encryption.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM profile
WHERE rtrim(ltrim(username))='AllenPHundleyo5Y3SDKs8bGmailmFaGC4r2xvcom'
```

Comment: This was it. Simple matter. I left spaces in it. Stupid mistake, but leaving the question in case others make the same mistake.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times on stackoverflow @Allenph but maybe... :)